# What to Assert or expect when checked exception occurs in Mockito Junit test

Tags: java, junit, mockito

How to run a JUnit Test case on Checked Exception.
For e.g. HttpClient execute method shows checked IOException but i am not sure what to assert/expect.

```
    import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
            import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
            import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpUriRequest;
        
             @Test
              public void throwIOExceptionOnHttpRequest() {
                HttpClient httpClient = mock(HttpClient.class)
                HttpUriRequest httpUriRequest = mock(HttpUriRequest.class);
          
    try{   
  when(httpClient.execute(any(HttpPost.class))).thenThrow(IOException.class);
         httpClient.execute(httpUriRequest);
                //Ideally nothing should work after this as exception is thrown
                        //fail("This will fail") // this statement will throw Assertion Error
                    }
                    catch (IOException io) {
                    
                    }
                }
```

If i try using expected method, this returns IOException never thrown.

```
 Exception thrown =
                  assertThrows(
                          IOException.class,
                          () -> {
                           when(httpClient.execute(any(HttpPost.class))).thenThrow(IOException.class);
                          });
    
          Truth.assertThat(thrown).hasMessageThat().contains("IOException");
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

In your test method you only stubbed `httpClient.execute` method, but never called it. That is why no exception has been thrown.

On top of that:

- it is unclear what is object under test. Mock collaborators, not object under test.
- if you only assert on message containing "IOException" string, you may prefer to assert that it is the instance of that class.

Comment: i have updated the full test case, isn't this a call when(httpClient.execute(any(HttpPost.class))).thenThrow(IOException.class); 
What objects you think are missing.

Comment: `when(httpClient.execute(any(HttpPost.class))).thenThrow(IOException.class);` only configures the mock object to respond a call to `httpClient.execute` with any `HttpPost` by throwing. After configuring the mock, you need the actual call. Please get familiar with https://javadoc.io/doc/org.mockito/mockito-core/latest/org/mockito/Mockito.html#2

Comment: `What objects you think are missing:` you only showed us the mock. configuring a mock to throw on a call to method, and calling that method directly is not useful. You need to mock collabolators of object under test, not object under test itself.

Comment: i can only make call through mocked objects, added httpClient.execute(httpUriRequest) but still i cannot use fail().

Comment: 1. You have a test, but it is not testing your code. 2. Your stubbing is still incorrect: you stub on HttpPost, which is more specific than HttpUriRequest, hence you get no exception.

Comment: My original class only throws checked IOException, i never seen throwing IOException at runtime.

Answer (score 0):

If I correctly understood, You need annotation @Test. And you should assign field "expected" your exception class.

```
@Test(excepted = IOException.class)
testMethod() {
     throw new IOException();
}
```

Comment: Fedor, expected=IOException.class never happens.